# How to parse date in "2022-03-04T10:30:00-08:00" format correctly in swift?

Tags: swift, datetime

I have date coming from API shown below. These dates are for different countries.

```
 dateTime = "2022-03-04T14:30:00-08:00"
```

I need to convert this use it both as Date and as String. But I do not know if date and time I am converting are correct. I am using following code:

To Convert String from API to Date:

```
extension String {
    var CommonDateFormat: Date? {
        get {
            let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
            dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ"
            return dateFormatter.date(from: self)
        }
     }
   }
```

To Convert Date to String:

```
extension Date {
    func getDateAccoringTo(format: DateFormat ) -> String {
        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = format.rawValue
        dateFormatter.timeZone = .current
        dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone.init(identifier: "UTC")
        return dateFormatter.string(from: self)
    }
}

enum DateFormat: String {
    case ddmmyyyy = "dd/MM/yyyy"
    case mmddyyyy = "MM/dd/yyyy"
    case mmmd_yyyy = "MMM d, yyyy"
    case llll_yyyy = "LLLL ,yyyy"
    case TIME = "HH:mm:ss"
    case day = "dd"
}
```

When I try to get day from date it always gives next day date. For example if date = "2022-03-04T14:30:00-08:00" then if I try to get day using code below

```
date?.getDateAccoringTo(format: .day)
```

This returns 5 not 4

```
date?.getDateAccoringTo(format: .TIME)
```

This returns time 00:00:00

Am I missing something important which is leading to these values?
Also, if I am missing something in my question kindly let me know so that I can improve it.

Answer (score 2):

The given string

```
let dateTime = "2022-03-04T14:30:00-08:00"`
```

is a standard ISO8601 formatted date string. It can be converted to `Date` with

```
let formatter = ISO8601DateFormatter()
let date = formatter.date(from: dateTime)!
```

At this specific point in time it is

- 14:30 on Friday, March 4 in Denver, CO, USA
- 22:30 on Friday, March 4 in London, UK
- 06:30 on Saturday, March 5 in Tokyo, Japan

Now let's see how Xcode displays dates.

- `print` displays `Date` instances always in `UTC` indicated by +0000 which is the London time zone unless you `print(date.description(with: .current)`, this displays the date in the local time zone.
- In a Xcode Playground the result area displays `Date` instances in the local time zone except in `print` lines.

Last point to consider is that `DateFormatter` converts `Date` to `String` in the local time zone if no time zone is specified.

---

Keeping this behavior in mind you get **the next day** if you convert the date to string with `DateFormatter` but without specifying the time zone and your local time zone is greater than or equal to +01:30.

And you get **the time 00:00** if you convert the date to string with `DateFormatter` but without specifying the time zone and your local time zone is exactly +01:30 which is a pretty unusual time zone by the way.

Comment: Also in Date extension, timezone is set twice .

Comment: @PtitXav Yes, I don't know what and if this the **real** code is because there is also no `.day` case in the enum. So my considerations are more general.

Comment: @PitXav Thank you. I will try and update you soon.

Comment: @vadian Yes this is real code. I was trying to execute using different ways so that's why there are some missing or multiple values. I have updated my question. Thank you for pointing that.

Comment: If the time zone is set to UTC this date cannot produce a different day nor the time 00:00.

Comment: @vadian Ok I will check and post an update soon